# PHP : no return selected checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, file, checkbox

I am new to php code, this is my first one.
Here I list the contents of a directory and list it with checkboxes.
My final goal is to be able to make one or more selections and delete them.
But I am unable to retrieve the value of the select boxes.
My return value is empty. (no error message).
Please, Can you point me on the right path?
Thanks

My index.php

```
<head>
    <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/css.css" />
</head>

<form>

    <fieldset>
    
        <br><legend>select files to delete :</legend> 

        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
                
            <?php
                
                
                
                    $directory = "./tmp";
                                                
                    $list = array_slice(scandir ($directory), 2);
                
            
                    
                    foreach ($list as $file) {
                    
                        $value= "./tmp/$file";
                        
                        if (is_file ($value)){ // files only
                            
                            echo "
                            <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value=$value>$file<br>
                            ";

                        }
                    }   

            ?>
            
            
        <br><input type="submit" name="button" value="DELETE FILES" />
                
        </form>

<!--  return selected checkboxes -->

        <h1>$_POST</h1>

        <?php
         if(isset($_POST["button"]))
         {
            if (isset($_POST['chk'])){
                var_dump($_POST);
            }
        }
        ?>
    
    </fieldset>
    

</form>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `value=$value` to `value='$value'` on the `input`?

Comment: same result with value='$value'

Comment: Why are you embedding 2 forms for?

Comment: Please check if you have data in `$list` and your condition works `if (is_file ($value))` (`$value` is file or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There were 2 forms
(Also, I have restructured your code)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    if (isset($_POST['chk'])){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
?>
<fieldset>
    <br><legend>select files to delete :</legend> 
    <form method="POST" action="">        
        <?php
            $directory = "./tmp";                          
            $list = array_slice(scandir ($directory), 2);
            foreach ($list as $file) {      
                $value= "./tmp/$file";
                
                if (is_file ($value)){ // files only
                    
                    echo "
                    <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='$value'>$file<br>
                    ";

                }
            }   
        ?> 
        <br><input type="submit" name="button" value="DELETE FILES" />         
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Chilarai, Both forms were for css, but this is definitely not the best practice. thank you your solution works. error was therefore in <form method ? Arman, yes I have data in $ list and the condition works if (is_file ($ value)). Thanks

Comment: @Claude yes. Error was due to 2 forms. The outer form always sent get request and the inner post request was never sent